# Populating a drop down list in JSP from a Array List of Bean type

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, arraylist, jstl

In my Java EE project I have the following Servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TitlePopulatorServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/TitlePopulatorServlet")
public class TitlePopulatorServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public TitlePopulatorServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("Inside doGet()!");

        ArrayList<BeanTitle> bt=new ArrayList<BeanTitle>();

        java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html"); 

        Connection conn=null;


        try {
            /* get the DataSource from using the JNDI name */
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/Test");

            //Create connection and then continue as usual other JDBC calls 
            conn=ds.getConnection();
            System.out.println("\nConnection Successful in TitlePopulatorServlet !");
            Statement s= conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM story");

            while (rs.next() ) 
            {
                BeanTitle b = new BeanTitle();
                b.setBtitle(rs.getString(1));
                bt.add(b);
            }

        } catch (Exception e){
            out.println("Failed!"+ e);
        }


            request.setAttribute("bt", bt);                                                         
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/StoryTitlePage.jsp").forward(request,response);


    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



    }
}
```

The BeanTitle is as follows:

```
public class BeanTitle 
{
    private String btitle;

    public String getBtitle() {
        return btitle;
    }

    public void setBtitle(String btitle) {
        this.btitle = btitle;
    }
}
```

And the JSP page ("StoryTitlePage.jsp") is as follows:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


<html>
<head>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<jsp:useBean id="storylist" class="serv.TitlePopulatorServlet" scope="request" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Story Title Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/ReportData/DisplayReport" method="post" >

        Please select an element: 

        <select id="selectedRecord" name="selectedRecord">

            <c:forEach var="item" items=${storylist.bt} >
                <option>${item.tarr}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I launch the TitlePopulatorServlet on the server it doesn't work. 
Where am I going wrong in the iteration/EL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The servlet store the list in the request, under the attribute named "bt". So it's already there, in the request. There is no need to do

```
<jsp:useBean id="storylist" class="serv.TitlePopulatorServlet" scope="request" />
```

That will only create a new instance of your servlet, which doesn't make any sense. and bt is a request attribute. It's not a property of the servlet. So using `${storylist.bt}` doesn't make any sense either.

You want to iterate over the elements of `bt`, so all you need is

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${bt}">
```

Finally, each item of `bt` is of type `BeanTitle`. And you're doing

```
${item.tarr}
```

This is equivalent to calling

```
beanTitle.getTarr()
```

And there is no tarr property in BeanTitle. The only property is `btitle` (since the only getter of the class is named `getBTitle()`).

So what you must use is

```
${item.btitle}
```

Your naming is awful, and that only makes you more confused. Why don't you use real words to name your classes and properties? Like for example

```
public class Book {
    private String title;

    public String getTitle() 

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the classic explanation! But after all the corrections it shows this error: message java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTag 

I've included the JSTL1.2.jar, jstl-impl.jar.
and I have also ensured
 1) That the jar files are sitting in the lib folder under WEB-INF and not just referenced in the build path. 2) The tomcat 8 runtime library is included in my build path

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info for where to download and how to install the JSTL.