# Calling getter method in JSP Spring form tag

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I am reading four columns form DB and preparing them to display by using jsp and spring form tags. I am able read them using hibernate and added the entire list to model. Now, how can i read them and display in dropdowns. 
 My Pojo looks like this

```
class bean{

String name;  //represents a column in DB
Sting id  
String some;
String data;
//getters and setter
```

and in my model i am returning as a list

```
List<bean> invoiceData = servicedao();
model.addAttribute("listdb", invoiceData);
```

How should i display now in jsp all coloumn values like

```
invoiceData.getsome();//using getters reading cell value
```

Can any one help me on this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `path="listdb,some"` in your Spring control tags. By the way method name shall be `getSome()` not `getsome()`.

Comment: Use EL and JSTL like :
<c:forEach items="${listdb}" var="bean">
  ${bean.name},
  ${bean.some}.....
</c:forEach>

Comment: I found the solution here for this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474836/populating-a-drop-down-list-in-jsp-from-a-array-list-of-bean-type

Answer (score 0):

Use JSTL to loop through and display data.

```
<c:forEach items="${listdb}" var="invoice">
name : ${invoice.name}
..... 
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate `List<bean>` through java or `JSTL`.

For `JSTL` you need to add `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>` taglib in `JSP` head.

now iterate values using JSTL foreach

```
<c:forEach items="${listdb}" var="bean">
   //var bean is used to get bean value on every iteration
   name = ${bean.name}
   some = ${bean.some}
   data = ${bean.data}
</c:forEach>
```